# Encryption of datasource password in JBoss without the application policy

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, encryption, jboss, encryption-symmetric

The main restriction is that for different clients I must have different databases with different credentials.
So I must create, for new clients, data sources on the fly (without restarting JBoss):

```
<datasources>
   <xa-datasource>
     <jndi-name>jdbc/1349173612812_ARCHIVE_001DS</jndi-name>
     <isSameRM-override-value>false</isSameRM-override-value>
     <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
     <xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:sqlserver://DEVDB\MYDB;databaseName=DEV_ARCHIVE_001</xa-datasource-property>
     <xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">DEV_ARCHIVE_001</xa-datasource-property>
     <xa-datasource-property name="SelectMethod">cursor</xa-datasource-property>
     <xa-datasource-property name="User">admin</xa-datasource-property>
     <xa-datasource-property name="Password">plain text password</xa-datasource-property>
  </xa-datasource>
</datasources>
```

Everything works fine, but know I must encrypt the passwords, for security measures.

I found the solution using `application policy` but in order for a policy to be visible to JBoss the server must be restarted - which is not an option for me.

Is there another method of securing the password?

Comment: it sounds to me you don't need to create datasource *instances* on the fly, which would be easier, but datasource *configurations*. You also didn't specify if you want to do this via jboss userspace application, jboss admin tools, other scripting tools or what?

Comment: Have you looked at the JBoss Vault password storage@ https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7SecuringPasswords.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://docs.jboss.org/jbosssecurity/docs/6.0/security_guide/html/Encrypting_Data_Source_Passwords.html) will help to Encrypt the password.

Answer (score 0):

The class org.jboss.resource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule can be used to both encrypt database passwords and to provide a decrypted version of the password when the data source configuration is required by the server. The SecureIdentityLoginModule uses a hard-coded password to encrypt/decrypt the data source password.

The data source password is encrypted using the SecureIdentityLoginModule main method by passing in the clear text password. The SecureIdentityLoginModule is provided by jbosssx.jar.

This procedure is for JBoss Enterprise Application Platform versions 5.1 and later

1. GoTo Jboss directory or  Change directory to the jboss-as directory
    for Example  user/demo/Jboss/

   **Linux command**

java -cp client/jboss-logging-spi.jar:lib/jbosssx.jar org.jboss.resource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule PASSWORD

or

java -cp bin/client/jboss-logging-spi.jar:standalone/lib/ext/jbosssx.jar org.jboss.resource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule PASSWORD

**Windows command:**
java -cp client\jboss-logging-spi.jar;lib\jbosssx.jar org.jboss.resource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule PASSWORD

Result:

The command will return an encrypted password.

> **Important Note**

:If you got error after executing this command 
 In this case check , you should have  " jbosssx.jar ", " jboss-logging-spi.jar " in your jboss.
it should be under lib directory or may in standalone/lib/ext/
(In the cammand it's taking path for this jar to encrypt the password)